# iOS CoreData custom search cancel on text field change

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, search, core-data

I have a TextField that is search in my app, I have added the event Editing Changed, but when I type fast CoreData is not able to search so rapidly so the results are not precise.

Currently I'm using such script:

```
[self->_searchThread cancelAllOperations];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(performSearch:) object:((UITextField *)sender).text];
[self->_searchThread addOperation:operation];
```

in performSearch I add all the predicates run through results and format them and then call:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setSearchResults:) withObject:@[[NSArray arrayWithArray:data]] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I thought using `[self->_searchThread cancelAllOperations];` would cancel current request and start a new one immediately but it does not seem to work like that. Is there any way I can cancel the current running search and start new once user changes the TextField, or are there any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a question: why aren't you using a UISearchBar with all the delegates for search inputs etc?

Comment: Because I have customized layout and UISearchBar does not fit in overall layout - I tryed.

Comment: Regarding @Alice's comment and your response, you are able to manipulate the size of a `UISearchBar` with the convenience (initialiser) method `initWithFrame:`, and because a `UISearchBar` has a `frame` property you can adjust the `frame` dynamically during code execution.

Comment: Regarding your question, have you considered creating an `NSArray` of all the `fetchedObjects` from your `NSFetchedResultsController` instance? I suspect it may be faster to apply your same predicate to such an `NSArray` using the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` method.

Comment: That would be bad, because there are a lot of elements and I would use three arrays, because of relationships, but I thinks I found a solution, I put the search thread(NSManagedObject) to sleep for 200ms and right after that I added 'if(isCancelled) return;' So if user types fast the CoreData does not get initialized.